# "Meta-logic" and "object-logic" (as word) definition in Isabelle

Tags: definition, isabelle, theorem-proving

What is the formal and complete definition of the words "meta-logic" and "object-logic" in Isabelle? I see people keep using these but could not find any definition for these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't find them because they are specific to Isabelle (as far as I know). "Object-logic" and "meta-logic" are terms introduced by Larry Paulson (as far as I can tell). In general, though not specifically, they are related to the general terms "metalanguage" and "object language", for disciplines like logic and set theory. Do a search on those and you'll get the standard wiki pages, because they're a standard part of logic.

Here, I'm looking at page 16, *2.2.3 Meta and object language* of *Logic and Computation - Interactive Proof with Cambridge LCF*, by Larry Paulson, published 1987. At that time he was still conforming to standard terms, but then he switched. I forgot where I read it, but he made the switch somewhere to "meta-logic" and "object-logic", to clarify things for his own purpose. The two terms are in his papers and in the Isabelle distribution docs.

Others can give you their expert knowledge, but the meta-logic specifically is what you get when you import the theory `Pure`, in particular, a minimal set of logical connectives, `==>`, `\<And>`, `&&&`, and `==`. Discussion of these are spread throughout the Isabelle distribution documentation.

I know nothing much about intuitionistic logic, other than it doesn't provide the law of excluded middle, but you will read that they provide a *minimal, intuitionistic logic*.

Don't thank me. I've just read some things here and there, and listened. Others can provide expert knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

My findings with regard this question are below.

I found in the [Clemens Ballarin slides, slide 20.](http://www21.in.tum.de/%7Eballarin/belgrade08-tut/session01/session01.pdf):

> *Meta logic*: The logic used to formalize another logic.
>
> Example: Mathematics used to formalize derivations in formal logic.

and it is put in parallel with:

> *Meta language*: The language used to talk about another language.
>
> Examples: German in a Spanish class, English in an English class.

Wikipedia has an entry on [Metalogic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalogic), one section is Metalanguage - Object language:

> In metalogic, formal languages are sometimes called object languages.
> The language used to make statements about an object language is
> called a metalanguage. This distinction is a key difference between
> logic and metalogic. While logic deals with proofs **in a formal system**,
> expressed in some formal language, metalogic deals with proofs **about a
> formal system** which are expressed in a metalanguage about some object
> language.

And here is slide 21 from [Ballarin](http://www21.in.tum.de/%7Eballarin/belgrade08-tut/session01/session01.pdf):

[image: Meta logic vs. object logic]